# problem while botting up (unable to show plymoth screen)

Tags: boot, startup, shutdown

From the time I installed the elementary os. Sometimes when I boot my system up then the system does not start, means the booting process does not work as usual so I need to shut down by pressing the power button hard, and after that, the error does not go and it shows as usual. After 4 or 5 attempts the error went away.
below is some screenshot of the error. It basically says

> recovering journal

and it continues infinite times[image: error]

[image: erro 2]

[image: error]

I am using

elementary OS 5.0 Juno Linux 4.15.0-47-generic GTK+ 3.22.30

and my system is

Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) 8.1 GB memory my laptop which contains ssd and hdd both . And I had completely installed linux on ssd and all goes fine.